# Grub2: no timeout on Fedora31

Tags: fedora, grub2

I've found many articles saying to edit `/etc/default/grub` and change to `GRUB_TIMEOUT=-1` .

There is much advice to then run `update-grub` which I don't have. [This site](https://linuxconfig.org/update-grub2-menu-timeout-on-rhel-7-linux) suggests instead `grub2-mkconfig -o /boot/grub2/grub.cfg` but I note I don't have an `/boot/grub2/grub.cfg` file before running this.  This website doesn't suggest anything else need be done, so I rebooted, and still had the same 5-second change timer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to [Fedora's Wiki](https://fedoraproject.org/wiki/GRUB_2#Updating_the_GRUB_configuration_file), it would be `sudo grub2-mkconfig -o /etc/grub2-efi.cfg` or `sudo grub2-mkconfig -o /etc/grub2.cfg`.